# Text overlapping issue only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, dojo

I have search box with text input and button input side by side with button inside the search box. On Internet Explorer, when we type a long string the text overlaps with the button. This works flawlessly with other browsers like firefox and chrome and text overlaps do not happen there.

HTML code:

```
<td style="width: 44%" align="right">
<div class="searchBox_div">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" style="background-color: white; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; border-color: black -moz-use-text-color black black; border-image: none; padding: 2px 15px 0 0; border-width: 1px;">
    <input type="button" id="overlay_search" title="Perform Search" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; padding: 5px 6px; border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
</div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.searchBox_div {
  display: inline-block;
  verticle-align: middle;
  background: #FFF url(/themes/default/images/glyphicons-halflings-black.png) no-repeat 5px 6px;
  position: relative;
}
.searchBox_div: before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
background: url(/themes/default/images/glyphicons-halflings-black.png) no-repeat center center;
width: 24px;
left: 4px;
top: 50 % ;
margin-top: -12px;
z - index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
}

.searchBox {
height: 30px;
width: 400px;
padding-left: 30px;
font-size: 20px;
}
.searchBox_div::-ms-clear {
width: 0;
height: 0;
display: none;
}
#overlay_search {
position: absolute;
background: url(/themes/default/images/glyphicons-halflings-black.png) no-repeat center center;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
right: -4px;
top: 50 % ;
background-position: -48px 5px;
margin - top: -11px;
z - index: 1;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay_cancel {
background-image: url("/themes/default/images/glyphicons-halflings-black.png");
background-position: -313px 5px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
height: 24px;
line-height: 14px;
margin-top: 0;
vertical-align: text-top;
padding: 2px 25px 0 0;
width: 14px;
}
```

I will post screenshot as soon as I get enough points on stackoverflow. I am trying something like this from Dojo Javascript which is partially working for me. But does not look as good as I want.

```
  if(dojo.isIE){
        on(dom.byId("search"), "focus", function () {
                style.set("search", "backgroundColor", "rgb(253,216,87)");
                style.set("searchBox_div", "border-width", "1px");
                style.set("searchBox_div", "backgroundColor", "rgb(253,216,87)");
                style.set("searchBox_div", "background-position-x", "15px");
        }); 
  }
```

Please help me fix this in internet explorer.

Comment: I tried uplaoding a preview image but need to gain reputation to do so

Comment: I take it your actual css doesn't have the spaces in-between yuor dashes: `inline - block;`

Comment: Can you pop this into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please... preferably without spaces in your css, eg `display: inline - block;`

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7zya95y6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding CSS and HTML right from stratch and removing absolute positioning and other unnecessary CSS.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="search" id="search" size="21" style="border:gray solid;border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="" id="overlay_search" class="tfbutton" style="border: 1px gray solid;height:22px;border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;"/>
 </div>    

.tftextinput{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
            width: 94px;
            height:10px;
            border:none;
}
.tfbutton {
    margin: 0px;
            height:20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
            background: url(/themes/default/images/glyphicons-halflings-black.png) #ffffff no-repeat center center;
            background-position: -47px 3px;
            border:none;
            width:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems only with the IE you can target your CSS only for IE different versions, i had this problems with different IE version and the solution below helped me a lot and still helping me:

check out browser compatibility: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

For example tell me in which version of IE u have problem:
and u can do something like this to create a css file and write inside the css

```
[if IE]
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css_that_will_affect_only_ie.css" />
[endif]
```

or u can do something like this

```
[if IE]
.searchBox_div {
  display: inline-block; // u change anything here
  verticle-align: middle;// u change anything here
  background: #FFF url(/themes/default/images/glyphicons-halflings-black.png) no-repeat 5px 6px;// u change anything here
  position: relative;// u change anything here
}
[endif]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. but can anyone guide me in formulating that conditional CSS?

Comment: This does not work on all versions of IE. Yes, I have already used the conditional CSS for IE in my code. I need inputs in defining the accurate CSS which will not break in any browser.

Comment: @rocktopus in which version all IE u have problems?

Comment: Yes this problem occurs in all versions of IE with above code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any difference in the explorer with your code. What i can advice you for this class

```
#overlay_search{
    right: -22px; // take it out completely from input field
}
```

if that will not help make a screenshot how is looking now and how u want that will look. And i will fix exactly as you wish.